# Apache's limit to POST request size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, post, passenger

Is there any limit of the `POST` request size in apache? What is the default value of this limit and is there any way to increase it? If it matters, `Rails` application is started on this server using passenger.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The limit in Apache is set via the `LimitRequestBody` directive and defaults to `0`:

> This directive specifies the number of bytes from 0 (meaning unlimited) to 2147483647 (2GB) that are allowed in a request body.

Take a look at the full description of Apache's [LimitRequestBody directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

Besides that `Rails` may impose a limit itself (cant't tell though b/c I've never programmed in Ruby).

Comment: While `LimitRequestBody` defaults to unlimited, note that `LimitXMLRequestBody` defaults to 1 MB.