# How to upload large files using react-native-image-crop-picker

Tags: android, react-native, file-upload, react-native-image-picker, react-native-image

I'm trying to upload small files using [react-native-image-crop-picke](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker)r it's working fine but when I tried uploading large video/image file using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-crop-picker) I'm getting Network error.

**Note :** Backend is working fine I'm able to upload file using Postman.

It's happening with large files only. I'm able to upload files that are smaller than 1MB

Code

```
   

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';
import axios from "axios";

function uploadFile(){

ImagePicker.openCamera({
  mediaType: 'any',
}).then(file=> {

   const body = new FormData();

    body.append('vurl', {
      name: file.fileName,
      type: file.mime,
      uri: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? file.path.replace('file://', '') : file.path,
    });

 
   axios({
      method:"post",
      url:"Server url",
      data:body,
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data",
      }
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.response);
      });

});

}



//calling here

<TouchableOpacity onPress={uploadFile}>
    <Text>upload file</Text>
<TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Can you attach the network error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check that you have set or not client_max_body_size in your backend for the server.
For Nginx :- /etc/nginx/proxy.conf

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

For more: [Increasing client_max_body_size in Nginx conf on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908426/increasing-client-max-body-size-in-nginx-conf-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: How is OP able to upload using Postman if Nginx doesn't allow large files?

Comment: Postman by default has 50 MB of file size in Settings and for Nginx default value for client_max_body_size is 1MB.

Comment: Yes, but the Postman request still has to go through Nginx which is at the default of 1MB (before making the change suggested in this answer). So how does the OP claim *Note : Backend is working fine I'm able to upload file using Postman.* @hemendra-khatik In any case, it is not obvious from the question that Nginx is being used.

Comment: It's just an example that I suggested. You can also check the "apache" request body limit via this example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686288/apaches-limit-to-post-request-size

Comment: Yes Nginx or Apache it doesn't matter. What I am unable to understand is if the request is going through with Postman, why is React failing? They are both hitting the exact same backend. So if Nginx/Apache/serverside was the problem it would also fail with Postman.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you don't have a default timeout defined in the code like:

`.defaults.timeout = x`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios#config-defaults

Answer (score -1):

I produced my suggestions by following directly from react-native-image-crop-picker example app repo [here](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/blob/master/example/app.js):

1. Set max height and width of what you're recording on camera. Example :

```js
ImagePicker.openCamera({
      mediaType: 'any',
      cropping: cropping, 
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
    }).then(file=> {
```

2. Compressing the quality of an image that you are picking

```js
 ImagePicker.openPicker({
      mediaType: 'any',
      compressImageMaxWidth: 1000,
      compressImageMaxHeight: 1000,
      compressImageQuality: 1, ----> you can set the value between 0 and 1 e.g. 0.6.
    })
    .then(file=> {.....
```

3. Set a max size should not exceed e.g. 1MB (whatever number you want) when you get the response before handling it further. Again I obtained file.size in the response section of the link above

```js
 ImagePicker.openCamera({
      mediaType: 'any',
    }).then(file=> {
    
       if (file.size > xxx) {
    Alert.alert('File size too large!') 
    //dont forget to import alert from react-native
    }
```